Sharing VPN connection with other machines on local network
Context
There's a VPN server where only a single machine I own is allowed to connect. Let's call this the machine A.
This VPN creates a sta0 device, but it doesn't route any traffic through it.
> route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1

Inspecting the device it creates, I get the following info:
> nmcli device show sta0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         sta0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            1280
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected (externally))
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     sta0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         100.65.0.2/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
...
a bunch of IP4.ROUTE lines
...
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fd20::a2/128
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fe80::3493:b46d:b30d:ee02/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fd20::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100, table=9
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = ::, mt = 100, table=9

Both machines' IPs are reserved in the local network, so they don't change.
The goal
I want to share this VPN connection with other machines on the same local network. To to achieve this goal, I installed an OpenVPN server on machine A and connected to it on the machine B through the local network. My plan was to route all network traffic from B through A.
The problem
For some reason, this setup didn't work. I tried debugging using traceroute.
Traceroute in machine A:
> traceroute site-accessible-through-vpn
traceroute to site-accessible-through-vpn (100.64.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
  -- just a bunch of * * * --

Traceroute in machine B without my OpenVPN server connected
> traceroute site-accessible-through-vpn
traceroute to site-accessible-through-vpn (111.111.111.111), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.1.1)  0.367 ms  0.352 ms  0.455 ms    <= my router
 2  192.168.15.1 (192.168.15.1)  2.227 ms  2.139 ms  2.287 ms    <= my ISP modem
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  187-100-57-95.dsl.telesp.net.br (187.100.57.95)  7.155 ms  7.236 ms  7.297 ms
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  111.111.111.111 (111.111.111.111)  4.433 ms  4.727 ms  8.773 ms


192.168.1.1 is my router's IP address
192.168.15.1 is my ISP modem's IP address

Traceroute in machine B with my OpenVPN server connected
> traceroute site-accessible-through-vpn
traceroute to site-accessible-through-vpn (111.111.111.111), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1)  50.939 ms  50.926 ms  50.917 ms
 2  _gateway (192.168.1.1)  52.538 ms  52.287 ms  52.490 ms
 3  192.168.15.1 (192.168.15.1)  52.494 ms  52.678 ms  52.473 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * 201-1-224-16.dsl.telesp.net.br (201.1.224.16)  230.319 ms  230.315 ms
 6  187-100-57-89.dsl.telesp.net.br (187.100.57.89)  230.137 ms 187-100-57-95.dsl.telesp.net.br (187.100.57.95)  33.937 ms 187-100-57-89.dsl.telesp.net.br (187.100.57.89)  33.923 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  111.111.111.111 (111.111.111.111)  10.903 ms  11.650 ms  11.177 ms

There's an additional hop to 10.8.0.1. This is machine A's IP in the OpenVPN network.
First thing I noticed is that the website is resolving to different IPs in each machine. It might imply, then, there's a different DNS server being used to resolve the names, but I don't know how to be sure.
If I disable the VPN connection (not the OpenVPN server I created, the first one) on machine A, the traceroute starts to look like the one on machine B.
Also, if I run a speed test on machine B, I can see a high network usage on machine A, indicating that the traffic is being redirected correctly.
The help I need
As my networking skills are far from good, I have no idea what I can do to make this work, so I came here to see if someone does.
I don't know if it's a DNS issue or if there are additional settings I have to do.
Thanks for the help!

To connect all machines in the client-side network to the server-network:

Make sure that you've enabled IP and TUN/TAP forwarding on the OpenVPN server machine.
Create the necessary client configuration directories (ccd) on Server-side and include the planned routing in there (see https://openvpn.net/community-resources/expanding-the-scope-of-the-vpn-to-include-additional-machines-on-either-the-client-or-server-subnet/)
Make sure to add manual routes also into the router for the devices on client-side in Order for them to Look up the Server network on the local IP of the VPN-client

